# Unreliable/Confusing MRTK Button Touch-Register Behaviour [Unity, Hololens2]

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

This issue turned up in a project during the development phase. MRTK Buttons have worked in this project/scene before. Unfortunately, it was not possible to trace back the cause yet.

Touch registers very unreliably with the Standard Hololens2 Button from the MRTK Toolbox. The only properties that were modified are the Transform of the GameObject, GameObject Name, Text and Icon.

A copy of the StartAdjustingGeometryButton GameObject as a child of Menus/MainMenu (left button in the Video) has the exact same settings displayed in the Inspector as the tested button but is even more unreliable.

Please see this video from my HL2 App for a demonstration:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33260631/113730570-4ba39680-96f8-11eb-91fe-5d51ce9531fc.mp4

Watching the video with sound makes it easier to notice when touch has been registered and when not.

See this Screenshot for the tested Button in the Inspector.
[image]

I'm using Unity Version 2019.4.20f1 and MRTK Version 2.6.1

What is going on? I hope someone can help - thanks!
Official bug report is here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/9624

Comment: I suspect the direct natural light introduced from the skylight disturbs the recognition of the hand tracking feature of HoloLens. Could you try to test it again in a well-lit room that does not have a lot of direct sunlight?

Comment: I've tried this in multiple environments and it has been the same problem everywhere. The lighting surely isn't the problem. But thanks anyways!

Comment: Hi @atie, we noticed that you shared your findings on GitHub. Could you share your solution after you confirmed it?

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT please check out my most recent comment: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/9624#issuecomment-822051709